# Add css class from database to manytomany field

Tags: python, css, django, checkbox

I am currently making a Form in which I have a many-to-many relationship displayed as checkboxes. Now I know how to add a class to a single field but how can I add a class to each checkbox of the many to many field? There are 3 possible classes and every checkbox should have a number of 1-3 like in the database so I can work with JS afterwards.

This is my Form:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    year_range = range(1996, 1920, -1)
    person_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    person_birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=year_range, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    person_password.label = 'Passwort'
    person_birthdate.label = 'Geburtsdatum'
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'person_interests': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                   'person_psycho': forms.HiddenInput}
        model = Person
```

And this is my model of the checkboxes which need the class:

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    interest_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    interest_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    interest_kind = models.ForeignKey(KindOfInterest)
    interest_weight = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.interest_name
```

As far as I know I can't just go for a `attrs={'class': self.id}` within the form. So how do I access this data in  a way that does still look good and won't need 30 lines of code? (The data I need is the `interest_kind = models.ForeignKey(KindOfInterest)` which is a foreing key but I don't think it makes any difference)

Comment: To me it looks like you need a custom widget. This widget will create a set of checkboxes and apply your custom classes to every single element of the set

Comment: Hmm so that means there is basically no simple function that comes out of the box with django?

Comment: Not as far as I can see. But maybe somebody else does know something. 
You could still apply the classes with your template file however. It might not be the most beautiful code, but it might get you there a bit quicker. When displaying those checkboxes you can iterate over the set and use the {{forloop.counter}} to append an index to the class name like <input class="myClass-{{forloop.counter}} ..>
While I consider it a bit hacky, it does certainly work :-)

Comment: yeah I tried to avoid that but I guess I have to hack around it... Still thanks for your help^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to add a custom class that extends Django's `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, which can be used for M2M relationships. You'll find it in: `django.forms.widgets`. In that class, is a `render` method that you can override.

Example:

```
class BootstrapCheckboxSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    """Form widget that supports Bootstrap's markup requirements"""
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if value is None:
            value = []
        has_id = attrs and 'id' in attrs
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        output = []
        # Normalize to strings
        str_values = set([force_unicode(v) for v in value])
        for i, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices,
            choices)):

            # If an ID attribute was given, add a numeric index as a suffix,
            # so that the checkboxes don't all have the same ID attribute.

            # Should be able to pass in additional widget attributes to
            # the checkbox renderer here...
            if has_id:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='{}_{}'.format(attrs['id'], i))
                label_for = u' for="{}"'.format(final_attrs['id'])
            else:
                label_for = ''

            cb = CheckboxInput(final_attrs,
                check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)

            option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
            rendered_cb = cb.render(name, option_value)
            option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
            output.append(u'<label{} class="checkbox">{} {}</label>'.format(
                label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

Then specify the class for your field:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    class Meta:
        widgets = {'person_interests': BootstrapCheckboxSelectMultiple,
                   'person_psycho': forms.HiddenInput}
        model = Person
```

Of course, you can name the class whatever you want. Hope that helps you out.